# Error 401 and API V1.1 Python

Tags: python, api, authentication, tweepy

Good morning,
I am trying to download the people that is twitting certain words in an area by this python code:

```
import sys
import tweepy

consumer_key="LMhbj3fywfKPNgjaPhOwQuFTY"
consumer_secret="   LqMw9x9MTkYxc5oXKpfzvfbgF9vx3bleQHroih8wsMrIUX13nd"
access_key="3128235413-OVL6wctnsx1SWMYAGa5vVZwDH5ul539w1kaQTyx"
access_secret="fONdTRrD65ENIGK5m9ntpH48ixvyP2hfcJRqxJmdO78wC"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
   def on_status(self, status):
       if 'busco casa' in status.text.lower():
           print (status.text)

def on_error(self, status_code):
    print (sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code)
    return True # Don't kill the stream

def on_timeout(self):
    print (sys.stderr, 'Timeout...')
    return True # Don't kill the stream
sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener()) 
sapi.filter(locations=[-78.37,-0.20,-78.48,-0.18])
```

I am getting this error:
Encountered error with status code: 401

I read in this link https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes that the error is caused by: 
Authentication credentials were missing or incorrect.
Also returned in other circumstances, for example, all calls to API v1 endpoints now return 401 (use API v1.1 instead).

The authentication is there with updated keys. How should I use API v1.1?

Thanks,
Anita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it says that your credentials are incorrect, you might want to check your credentials: you need to remove the whitespaces in your consumer secret for your code to work.

Also, I just tested your credentials (without whitespaces) and they are working. I can do whatever I want on behalf of your application. I suggest you very quickly go to https://apps.twitter.com and generate new ones. Never share your credentials. Especially online where everyone can see them.

Comment: Can you please confirm that what API version is being used by the "tweepy" library?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question.